# Can I use Ethereum on my mobile phone?

Tags: clients, mobile-wallet

What are the options to use Ethereum on my mobile (Android) smartphone? Is there a "mist for mobile"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not yet. You are referring to DApps running on mobile devices, I think.

There are apps available which offer ethereum-related services like [[1]](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mickdegraaf.etheralert) but they certainly query some nodes via RPC which removes the decentralization aspect.

As of today, there are no light clients for mobile available yet. A mist for mobile has yet to be implemented.

Comment: Mobile clients builds are available for both Go and C++ clients, though they are experimental

Comment: There are experimental iOS & android Geth builds [available here](https://github.com/karalabe/geth-sandbox) but running a full node on a mobile is probably a bad idea best to wait for a light client.

Comment: for info: Geth with experimental light client support can be found at https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/tree/light-stable. I don't however know if/how builds for mobile can be created from it.

Answer (score 3):

Check this out! https://github.com/syng-im

Syng is a mobile client for ethereum it is an initial release of the Syng client. Mainly to demonstrate proof of concept and encourage developer contribution.

I hope its what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

BlockApps provides a RESTful interface to build dapps on Ethereum. You would interact with a deployed strato node just like any other rest service.

http://www.blockapps.net/

Answer (score 1):

WallETH aims to fill this gap - but we are not there yet. http://walleth.org

Answer (score 0):

Bianchetto is a early-stage Ethereum Developer Framework for iOS, it also comes with a SDK for the JSON RPC API, you may want to check it out. https://github.com/bpolania/Bianchetto